# What is this columnar cactus?

Tags: identification, cactus

I am trying to identify my cactus that I planted when I xeriscaped last year. I never saved the little stick thing. I thought it was just a saguaro variation, but then it popped out all these red fingers. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Did you do this landscaping yourself or did you hire a professional?  If so, they would have design and plant materials used on file.  One note of something I see in your photos...that rock is too close to your siding of stucco.  I'd move those river stones away to try to get 4" below your siding or at least so they don't touch.  Believe it or not rocks can hold and splash water up onto the bottom of your siding and cause it to disintegrate.

Answer (score 5):

It's a Cleistocactus variety, just not sure which, maybe C. smaragdiflorus, though the flowers on that one usually have a greenish tip, see here http://zipcodezoo.com/index.php/Cleistocactus_smaragdiflorus. The hairs/spines on the stems of your plant don't look silvery enough to be C. straussii either. C. hyalacanthus is another possibility, and that variety does have 'hairy' or furry flowers, like yours, but often has a non hairy or darker patch on top of the stems which I'm not seeing in your pics, so I'm afraid I can't say 100% which variety it is. Information about Cleistocactus generally here  http://dendro.cnre.vt.edu/dendrology/syllabus/factsheet.cfm?ID=933